# Continuous and differentiable sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider $$\sum_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{|n|}(1+n^2)}e^{inx}  $$ 
I wish to determine if the sum is continuous and differentiable. In fact, according to the exercise, i know it is... but I can't get to that conclusion, and actually get the opposite conclusion, so what is the correct method here?

I admit I just want an answer, but it's not homework. Just genuinely curious.

Comment: It is the same as $$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{2 \cos (nx)}{\sqrt{n}(n^2+1)}$$, which converges uniformly by Weierstrass' M-Test.

Comment: Okay, this obviously converges uniformly. But the derivative does ... not? The $n$from within the $\cos$ pops out and ruins the convergence, no?

Comment: No. Derivatives converge uniformly as well. Note that the derivative is bounded by $$\sum_n \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n}(n^2+1)} < + \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the partial sums of $\cos(nx)$ are bounded, the series:

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^{\alpha}}$$ 
is pointwise convergent on $(0,\pi/2)$ for any $\alpha>0$ by [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

I think you can get it from there.